# Unable to delete a GCP Project. It prompts "Project Service Unknown error"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I created a test project using Google Cloud Platform and i want to shutdown it, But when i tried to do so it gives me the following error. 
"Project Service
Unknown error
Tracking number: 4304144073534280568"

[image]

Comment: Are you following **[Shutting down (delete) projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects)** guide using the Console? Have you performed the same action of deleting your project repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, in Cloud Console -> Settings page. Yes, i tried several times and the same error prompted.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete all services under the project, then delete the project.

Go to endpoints -> services, and see the link for deleting the service: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/endpoints/services/delete

1. Delete "developer portals" for you API, this can be done thru web UI
2. Then, delete the service itself "gcloud endpoints services delete [your-app-services-name].appspot.com --project [your-project-id]"

Answer (score 0):

If after having followed **[Shutting down (delete) projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects)** guide, **you are still unsuccessful to shut down or delete your project**, I would recommend you do the following:

> **Please refer to this [form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) to open a case with the Google Cloud Platform Billing Support team. They will respond to any questions about your billing account or project settings.**

Hope this helps.